# General Topology: Quotient Map

Tags: general-topology

Take $X,Y$ to be two topological spaces.

$p: X \to Y$ be continuous

Suppose $\ f: Y \to X$ such that  $\ p \circ f = id_Y$.

Claim: $p$ is a quotient map.

It suffices to show that $p$ is surjective and sets are open in X $\iff$ open in Y.

$\bf{Surjectivity}:$ We know $p(f(x))=id_Y$ does this mean that $f(x)=y$? If so, we're done.

What does this notion of "right inverse" mean?

Comment: You need $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: "sets are open in $X$ $\iff$ open in $Y$": it's better to say that a subset $V$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}[V]$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p:X\to Y$, $f:Y\to X$ are continuous function between topological space such that $p\circ f=\mathrm{id}_y$, then $p$ is a quotient map.

For $y\in Y$ we have $p(f(y))=y$, hence $p$ is surjective.
Let $V$ be a subset of $Y$.
If $V$ is open, then $p^{-1}[V]$ is open because $p$ is continuous.
Conversely, if $p^{-1}[V]$ is open, then $V=f^{-1}[p^{-1}[V]]$ thus $V$ is open in $Y$ because $f$ is continuous.